# Values appear as the class name in the listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox

I'm reading in a field from a database into a list, like so

```
PaceCalculator pace = new PaceCalculator();
List<PaceCalculator> Distancelist = new List<PaceCalculator>();
while (Reader.Read()) //Loops through the database and adds the values in EventDistance to the list
{
    pace.Distance = (int)Reader["EventDistance"];
    Distancelist.Add(pace);
}
```

I want to put the values into a listbox, but when I do it like this:

```
listBox1.DataSource = Distancelist;
```

It only shows the class name, which is `PaceCalculator`. It shows the right number of values, it just shows the class name instead. I want to see the integers in there.

Comment: Either override `ToString` in `PaceCalculator` or extract the values to a list of `int`s and bind to that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options,

- Override `ToString` in your class to return the required string
- *or*, if you only want to display `Distance` then specify that as `DisplayMember`

like:

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Distance";
listBox1.DataSource = Distancelist;
```

This will display you the Distance element from your list. Or you can override `ToString` in your class `PaceCalculator` like:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", property1, property2, property3);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment and looking at your code, You are doing one thing wrong.

> this only displays the last value in the list, 46, 8 times

You are adding the same instance (`pace`) of your class  in your list on each iteration. Thus it is holding the last value `(46)`. You need to instantiate a new object in the iteration like:

```
while (Reader.Read()) 
{
    PaceCalculator pace = new PaceCalculator();
    pace.Distance = (int)Reader["EventDistance"];
    Distancelist.Add(pace);
}
```

Comment: this only displays the last value in the list, 46, 8 times

Comment: @GeorgeBoulton, See the last part of my answer, you are modifying and adding the same object again and again , in your iteration.

Comment: @GeorgeBoulton, glad it did, I see that you haven't accepted any answers to your previous questions. You can mark any answer as accepted as you like. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Specify the property of `PaceCalculator` to display.

```
listBox1.DataSource = Distancelist;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Distance";
```

The `ListBox` control allows you to pick a property from the collection to display to the user.

There's also a `ValueMember` property that allows you to specify the value for each item in the `ListBox`. Assuming your data included an id called "SomeUniqueRecordId", for instance:

```
listBox1.ValueMember = "SomeUniqueRecordId";
```

Comment: This still displays just the class